# How do I make one child of a dom structure rise to the top of the DOM in React Native

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-native

I am working on a react native project where I have a `<View "container" >
 <Image/> <View "toucharea" /> </View>` being returned by an array with transforms being applied to the container view (making everything inside rotate, as seen below). However, I am aiming to have many of these elements and sometimes the tail end of the container view overlaps the `toucharea` and stops me from accessing its panhandlers.

How do I make the toucharea float to the top of the stack so that it is always the first item selected when I touch it?

Code:

```
output.push(<View>
{/* Container for an entire button */}
<View style={[ styles.cursorImageContainer, 
  { height: containerWidth, width: strokeWidth },
  {
    transform: [
      { translateX: containerWidth/2 - strokeWidth/2 },
      { rotateZ: startAngle *57.29582 + "deg" },
    ]
  }
]}>

  {/* First Cursor Image  */}
  <Image style={[ styles.image, 
  { height: containerWidth, width: strokeWidth/3 }]} 
  source={dialCursor}/>

  {/* First Touch Area  */}
  <View lineID={k} style={[ styles.cursorImageTouchArea, 
  { height: strokeWidth, width: strokeWidth/3 } ]}
  {..._startHandler}/>
</View> 

{/* Container for an entire button  */}
<View style={[ styles.cursorImageContainer, 
  { height: containerWidth, width: strokeWidth },
  {
    transform: [
      { translateX: containerWidth/2 - strokeWidth/2 },
    { rotate: (startAngle+angleLength)*57.29582 + "deg" },
  ]
}]}> 

  {/* Second Cursor image  */}
  <Image style={[ styles.image, 
  { height: containerWidth, width: strokeWidth/3 }
  ]} source={dialCursor}/> 

  {/* Second Touch Area  */}
  <View ref={(k) => this.currentLine = k} lineID={k} style={[ styles.cursorImageTouchArea, 
  { height: strokeWidth, width: strokeWidth/3 } ]}
  {..._endHandler}/>

</View>  
</View>
)
})
return output;
```

Stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  stackContainer: {
    // position: 'absolute',
  },
  svgElement: {
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  cursorImageTouchArea: {  
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    opacity: 0.15,
  },
  cursorImageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
     alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    position: 'absolute',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  textContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple answer to my own question.

All i had to do was use pointerEvents={'box-none'} in my cursorContainer View and also wrap the image in a view and give it pointerEvents={'none'}.

I tried using zIndex but it didnt work with children components.